# Creating an amplitude vs frequency spectrogram of an audio file in Python

Tags: python, audio, transform, fft, spectrogram

I am trying to create an amplitude vs frequency spectrogram of an audio file in Python. what is the procedure to do so?
Some sample code would be of great help.

Comment: Are you looking for [`scipy.signal.periodogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html) (or alternatively [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html)) ?

Comment: looking for a graph similar to the one on top here--https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1770704/figure/fig7/AS:303681250578449@1449414660437/Upper-graph-Fourier-spectrogram-for-the-AFOEV-data-taken-during-the-long-decline-after.png

Comment: That has quite possibly been generated by a simple FFT, something like `plot(np.fft.fftfreq(len(x)), abs(np.fft.fft(x)))`

Comment: could you give some sample code? would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple spectrum**

The simplest way to get an amplitude vs. frequency relationship for an evenly sampled signal `x` is to compute its [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) through the efficient [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm. Given a signal `x` sampled at a regular sampling rate `fs`, you could do this with:

```
import numpy as np
Xf_mag = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))
```

Each `index` of the `Xf_mag` array will then contain the amplitude of a frequency bin whose frequency is given by `index * fs/len(Xf_mag)`. These frequencies can be conveniently computed using:

```
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Xf_mag), d=1.0/fs)
```

Finally the spectrum could be plotted using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(freqs, Xf_mag)
```

**Refining the spectrum estimation**

You might notice that the spectrum obtained with the simple FFT approach yields a spectrum which appears very noisy (ie. with lots of spikes). 
To get a more accurate estimate, a more sophisticated approach would be to compute a [power spectrum estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation) using techniques such as [periodograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram) (implemented by [`scipy.signal.periodogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html)) and [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) (implemented by [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html)). Note however that in these cases the computed spectrum is proportional to the square of the amplitudes, so that its square root provide an estimate of the Root-Mean-Squared (RMS) amplitudes.

Going back to the signal `x` sampled at a regular sampling rate `fs`, such a power spectrum estimate could thus be obtained as described in the samples from scipy's documentation with the following:

```
f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
A_rms = np.sqrt(Pxx)
```

The corresponding frequencies `f` are also calculated in the process, so you could then plot the result with

```
plt.plot(f, A_rms)
```

Using `scipy.signal.welch` is quite similar, but uses a slightly different implementation which provides a different accuracy/resolution tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2  
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.25*time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*3e3*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

This is pulled from the scipy documentation as you will need scientific computing to create a spectrogram. 
install scipy on your machine if you do not have it already and read its documentation:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html

Comment: the code above is for frequency vs time. I am looking for amplitude vs frequency spectrogram.